# Best practice to deploy and reference files in gitignore

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Django app on Heroku.  As recommended for security, I don't want to commit and push my secret key from the settings.py file, so I put the key in a separate file and imported it into settings.py.  I put my file containing the secret key into .gitignore so that it doesn't get committed.

Now the problem is when I'm pushing to Heroku, I get a ModuleNotFoundError - which makes sense because this file was never committed. Is there a workaround or best practice to use secret keys without exposing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you noticed what happened when you excluded the file: it's not there and this is exactly how the security is achieved. The obvious problem now is how does the program get access to the data anyway.

On Heroku, this in handled by setting environment variables on your app that you will then read out when initializing your program -- how this is done differs between programming languages.

So either go `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<your-app>/settings` and set the variables there. Or utilize the command-line tool like this:

```
heroku config:set KEY=value -a your-app
```

The next question then is how you handle this in for local development. A simple solution could be to check for the existence of the git-ignored file, and if it exists use it, otherwise read the values from the environment.